# Datatable cannot be transposed. "System.ArgumentException'

Tags: c#, epplus

I am exporting 3 tables here to Excel of which I want to transpose the first table only.  I tried using the Transpose function but it seems like I am using it in a wrong way as it throws System.ArgumentException. Not sure, what's the other way to transpose the table.

I also tried using DataView but even that did not work. Below is what I did with DataView:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strSql = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Sql"];
        DataAccess dsObj = new DataAccess();    
        DataSet ds= dsObj.GetData(strSql);
        DataView transposedDataView = Transpose(ds.Tables[0].Copy()).DefaultView;
        var td = transposedDataView.ToTable();
        TableData(td, ds.Tables[1], ds.Tables[2]);
    }
```

Below is the entire code

```
class CreateWorkbook
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strSql = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Sql"];
        DataAccess dsObj = new DataAccess();    
        DataSet ds= dsObj.GetData(strSql);
        TableData(Transpose(ds.Tables[0]), ds.Tables[1], ds.Tables[2]);
        }

    private static DataTable Transpose(DataTable dt)
    {
        DataTable dtNew = new DataTable();

        //adding columns    
        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dtNew.Columns.Add(i.ToString());
        }



        //Changing Column Captions: 
        dtNew.Columns[0].ColumnName = " ";



        //Adding Row Data
        for (int k = 1; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++)
        {
            DataRow r = dtNew.NewRow();
            r[0] = dt.Columns[k].ToString();
            for (int j = 1; j <= dt.Rows.Count; j++)
                r[j] = dt.Rows[j - 1][k];
            dtNew.Rows.Add(r);
        }

        return dtNew;
    }
    private static void TableData(DataTable Summary, DataTable NewIssue, DataTable Backlog) // Datatable contains data which we want to show in excel report
    {


          // create a new excel package for writing
            using (ExcelPackage workingPkg = new ExcelPackage())
            {


                //create workbook
                ExcelWorkbook wbReport = workingPkg.Workbook;

                //Add worksheets in workbook
                ExcelWorksheet ws = workingPkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Summary.xlsx");
                ExcelWorksheet ws1 = workingPkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("NewIssuance.xlsx");
                ExcelWorksheet ws2 = workingPkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("BuyBack.xlsx");


                ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(Summary, true, TableStyles.Medium1);
                ws.Cells[ws.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
                ws.Cells["A:H"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0";

                ws1.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(NewIssuance, true, TableStyles.Medium1);
                ws1.Cells[ws1.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
                ws1.Cells["A:H"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0";

                ws2.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(BuyBack, true, TableStyles.Medium1);
                ws2.Cells[ws2.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
                ws2.Cells["A:H"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0";


                                workingPkg.SaveAs(new FileInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Location"] + DateTime.Now.ToString("_MM_yyyy")+".xlsx"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I love it when people post a thousand lines of code and say "I'm getting an exception from somewhere in that lot" ... one of the basic bits of advice for an SO question is "imagine you're trying to explain your problem to a busy colleague.." - if you imagine yourepself as that colleague, would you find it easy to get to grips with the problem as explained here?

Comment: @CaiusJard And there are times when people say "How am I supposed to figure out from just 4 line of code, let us see what you've been doing. post the full code." That's the reason, I've posted the method usage(4 lines) first and then the entire code below that(if needed). I do know, what mistake I am probably making(calling the method in a wrong way), just need some help to rectify it.

Comment: I think, if I were coding this up, I wouldn't bother transposing the datatable, is just fill it into the sheet the other way round (do the transpose as i''m sheet filling)

Comment: But, if I do that, it would transpose all the tables, wouldn't it? I just want it for the first table.

Comment: What? If you only want to transpose one out of three tables, then only run one table through whatever code you write at transposes. For the other tables, just output them straight..

Comment: So what line is actually throwing the exception?

Comment: it throws exception at this line:  'ws1.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(NewIssuance, true, TableStyles.Medium1);' and it says System.ArgumentException occurred in  epplus.dll

Answer (score 0):

Try transposing the data into excel, rather than transposing the datatable and getting ExcelPackage to read the transposed table; datatables were never intended to be used that way round. DataTables are absolutely and totally intended to be a collection of data whose columns are consistently typed. You cannot take a 2 row table holding an int column and a string column and turn it into a pair of typeless columns, representing an int row and a string row.. DataTable cannot be made to work like that

I've never used ExcelPackage, so I don't warrant that the code below is 100% error free (for example I'm not sure if ExcelPackage uses 0 based or 1 based indexing etc); the idea was to show that you can iterate a datatable row by row, column by column, but you can write data into the excel sheet column by column, row by row, effectively transposing it

```
for(int tr=0;tr<table.Length;tr++)
  for(int tc=0;tc<table.Length;tc++)
    worksheet.Cells(tc,tr).Value = table.Rows[tr][tc];
```